# XP slow startup at "Loading personal settings" when connected to router, not otherwise

Tags: windows-xp, boot, delay

I have a 30-40 second delay on an XP Pro machine at the "Loading personal settings" stage of startup, but only when connected to a router. Only a few seconds when disconnected.

What could be the problem?  Is it maybe a startup process that is trying to connect to the internet?  Or maybe something to do with the local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a mapped network-drive that is trying to connect on startup.

When you have logged in, check *My Computer* and see if you have any network-drives. If so, try disconnecting them then reboot.

They should not be remapped by default on boot unless you specifically have them do so, in which case you need to know how they are being mapped. If you did not do it yourself, then check for startup entries (eg with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)) as well as [scripts](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/gptext_assigncomputerstartupscripts.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: It was the mapped drive - failing to connect and waiting for the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Set the primary DNS IP as your DC. Check for explicit scripts. Check for mapped drives, and if some drives are mapped over VPN. These are almost always the issue.